# How to write convergence in measure as union and intersections

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I know that if $f_{n} \to f$ $\mu$-a.e., then we have that:

$$\mu\left( \bigcup_{k} \bigcap_{N} \bigcup_{n\geq N} \{x: |f_{n}-f|\geq 1/k\} \right) = 0$$

Now I want to write something similar for convergence in measure (as I find this form is easy to work with in proofs). My guess would be that if $f_{n} \to f$ in measure then:

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sup_{n\geq N} \left[ \mu\left( \bigcup_{k} \{x: |f_{n}-f|\geq 1/k\} \right) \right] \right) = 0$$

Can anyone verify this? My intuition on this stuff is shaky at best so I am not sure if this is correct. If it isn't, can someone provide the correct representation? Most appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\bigcup_k \{x: |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq 1/k\} = \{x: |f_n(x)-f(x)| > 0 \}.$$

Therefore

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq N} \mu \left( \bigcup_k \{|f_n-f| \geq 1/k\} \right)=0$$

is equivalent to

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq N} \mu(|f_n-f| >0)=0.$$

This is not equivalent to convergence in measure. (Just consider e.g. the sequence $f_n(x) := \frac{1}{n}$ which converges pointwise to $f(x) := 0$ on $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1))$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure.)

Convergence in measure is equivalent to

$$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad \lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq N} \mu(|f_n-f| \geq 1/k) = 0.$$

This follows directly from the fact that for any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq [0,\infty)$, we have

$$a_n \to 0 \iff \lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq N} a_n = 0.$$

Comment: I suppose for that last part you are assuming that $a_n\geqslant 0$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yeah, thanks a lot.